# Is it possible to make a reverse RDP connection on windows server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, rdp

My Windows Server 2016 is behind a router, which i have no access to. So i can't open ports and do port-forwarding. I want to connect to my server via RDP. Sure I could use some 3rd party apps like Teamviewer, but is there a way to establish a RDP connection in reverse? Like running a powershell command on the windows server to a remote host (who is a real server with a static IP and is listening) and "invite" him to open a RDP connection to the server? Kind of like a real RDP connection, just in reverse.

I did not find a single result at google, seems like i am the only one who ever had this thought, so I guess it doesn't work that way, right? Any ideas on how to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0):

RDP does not support reverse (or "outgoing") connections in any way, sorry.

If I had to do something like this, I would use a outgoing SSH session on my server, with port forwarding configured on 3389, to a 3rd party host. You would be able to connect to the 3rd party host as you would to the windows server.

Answer (score 0):

```
seems like i am the only one
```

having an OWN server behind a FOREIGN Router and not gaining the access you need is indeed not a common problem tbh.

I would setup a VPN-(Client)-Connection from that server to whatever VPN-Server your server on the outside can offer - then you can access the jailed server at any time through the tunnel, using any service you like.

Comment: well sometimes guacamole is a nice peace of software for this kind of issue